# Reloading existing players and customization screens when returning to menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, menu, customization, multiplayer

I have a couch party game in unity played up to 4 players with Unity's new Input System.

I managed to make players join in the main menu with any button press and if they want they can proceed to character customization.

(all 4 players at once while each have a customization screen of their own on panels next to each other with a multiplayer event system which allows them to control their own panel individually)

Afterwards they can proceed to game each with their own customized player and play some.
when they finish the game they go back to the main menu and from here I need some help...

when the players return to the Main menu they are considered already join and because of that their customization panel wont be available because it is instantiated while player is joined for the first time while the instance of the main menu where it existed is no longer as returning to menu loads the main menu as new.

I want some help in figuring out a solution to this problem :)

I have tried looking for a way to save the menu's state and reload it when the players return to menu but I'm not sure if that's a legitimate way of doing so, anyone knows or can think of a better way?

Comment: Try to load MainMenu object from prefab (delet it from scene) and mark its root as DontDestroyOnLoad, then properly reset its state on session end.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually managed to find a solution.

I used UnityEngine.SceneManagement in order to access SceneManager,
in this I found the event - sceneLoaded that takes Scene & LoadSceneMode as arguments (sceneLoaded<Scene, LoadSceneMode>).

I implemented the logic of my customization menu to be applied once as usual and from here on to be called when this event calls.